# Web Scraping in Google Scholar with beautifulsoup and selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm trying to scrape from Google Scholar profiles. I need profiles with special specifications that I specified. I use Beautifulsoup and selenium in Python. For example, I need professors in a university that work on some subjects which I specified. What is your idea?

My way is very slow and needs to visit every profile page to check my special specifications. Please offer me a faster way if you know.

If exist a fast and better way to do this work, please say it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the subjects you need in the url like this:

https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:computer_vision+label:machine_learning

Here I'm searching for authors with two fields: computer vision and machine learning

Comment: If I want to scrape subjects from a particular university, what would you think?

Comment: I'm not sure about university, look like it has a reference id to specific university